# How to call a function only once when it scrolls to the bottom of a screen? - React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scroll

I currently have a function that loads information from the backend when I scroll to the bottom of a screen. The problem is that when I scroll to the bottom, it'll call the function multiple times when I only want it to run once.

The function I want to run:

```
const loadProgramList = () => {
    refreshToken()
      .then((refresh) => {
        return fetch("http://localhost:5000/program/load-program-list", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("accessToken")}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ index: index }),
        });
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          return response.json().then((data) => {
            throw { error: data.error, status: response.status };
          });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.success) {
          setPrograms((prevPrograms) => {
            return prevPrograms.concat(data.programs);
          });
          setIndex((prevIndex) => {
            return prevIndex + 10;
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response === 401) {
          Cookies.remove("accessToken");
          Cookies.remove("refreshToken");
          window.location.reload();
          ctx.setLoginModal(true);
          ctx.setStatus("Session timed out: You have been logged out");
        } else {
          navigate("/error", {
            state: { error: error.error, status: error.status },
          });
        }
      });
  };
```

I'm using useEffect() to check when the user has reached the bottom of the screen:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadProgramList();

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        loadProgramList();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [index]);
```

How can I make sure the function only runs once?

Answer (score 0):

`loadProgramList` will run every time when the `index` has changed.

When the scroll reach to the bottom your scroll event callback function will be fired and run `loadProgramList`. And it has `setIndex` logic. So this function will change your `index` state which is a trigger of your `useEffect` so the `useEffect` will be fired but you have `loadProgramList` in your effect callback function. So it will execute `loadProgramList` again.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    loadProgramList(); // This will run every time when index has changed.

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        loadProgramList(); // This will run when the scroll reach the bottom.
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [index]);
```

My suggestion is, get rid of the first `loadProgramList` in your effect. If you need to call this function in initial rendering you might want to execute this function only when the first time rendering.
You could use `useRef` for this. Something like this.

```
const firstRenderRef = useRef<boolean>(true)
...
useEffect(() => {
    if(firstRenderRef.current) {
      loadProgramList();
      firstRenderRef.current = false
    }
...
  }, [index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to implement an infinite scroll that loads data when you reach the bottom of the screen.

I don't understand why you put the scroll event inside `useEffect` for `index`. You need to separate these two things.

My suggestion is to add the scroll event handler one time when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // scroll event handler
}, []);
```

And now that I'm thinking about it, there's absolutely no reason to add the `useEffect` for `index` changes. So just remove it.

Also, it might be a good idea to *debounce* or *throttle* your scroll event handler for a better performance.